# Use of verb+ and +verb

Tags: conjunctions

In the following sentence

> 1. He decided *to* get up early, *to* wear nice dress and ***to*** visit his aunt.

Conjugation *and* is used. Since after and before *and* same proposition is used.
So my question is can we omit any of them and write

> 2. He decided to get up early, wear nice dress and  visit his aunt.

Or

> 3. He decided to get up early, to wear nice dress and  visit his aunt.

Comment: You need some commas.

Comment: @LucianSava i have edited question. Can we ommit to before latter verb

Comment: 2. is the most natural, though I would say "dress smartly" (or "wear nice clothes") rather than "wear nice dress".

Answer (score -1):

> Conjugation *and* is used.

should be:

> **Conjunction** *and* is used.

---

Sentence 1 is the most correct, as it implements the [parallel structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)).

Sentence 2 is also acceptable, it uses only one "to" for all verbs.

Sentence 3 is the least desirable, as there is no rule followed.